Testcontainer Integration Test works with mvn verify but not within Eclipse
On linux fedora I have a JUnit 5 integration test that starts and uses a org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
The test run successfully when using mvn clean verify
However, running them in Eclipse IDE leads to a
UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)

the docker.sock exists and Eclipse uses the same Java JRE that mvn uses. Does I need to give eclipse more rights to be able to see /var/run/docker.sock and if yes, how can I do that? I'm relatively new to linux. If you need more details to answer the question, please comment.
